# 3 questions about Bindingsource and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

in my application i have a from with bindingsource to entity.

Mybindingsource.datasource=(From t in context.mytable where .......
                           Select t).ToList

1) When i update a record on bindingsource , this record is updated on database.But if i add new record or delete a record on bindingsource , the database is not updated.What can i do?

2)How to detect if a record on bindingsource is changed? ( i want to enable a save button after this detection)

3.If a change a record in bindingsource , how can i undo the changes (before saving)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

1) When delete a record from bind source, you will need delete that record in you entity context.

```
dbContext.mytalbe.Remove(recordToRemove);
```

Same with add, you will need

```
dbContext.mytable.Add(newRecord);
```

Currently, I am using DevExpress grid with Entity 4.1, so it could be different with standard WinForm grid.

what I found out is that normally in your code of adding or remove record, you Add/Remove them directly into entity dbContext level then the change will be reflected on the components, otherwise add/remove wouldn't automatically done on
if you do other way around etc. add/remove them from binding side. I don't think you need do both, and I think make changes in the dbContext side is easier.

2) What I did is I check the state of the entity record, for example the following code is a function I used to detect whether the object has been modified.

```
public bool IsDirty(Purchase purchase)
        {
            bool result = false;

            if (this.dbContext.Entry(purchase).State != EntityState.Unchanged)
                result = true;

            return result;
        }
```

3) Before you save, nothing will be changed to the DB, right? So you can simple dispose your current dbContext and retrieve that data again from DB with the original data. That will be the most simple way I can think of.

Hope that will help you.